# How do I monitor and track the legal proceedings of Silk Road founder Ross Ulbricht?

Tags: legal, silk-road

I'm interested in tracking the litigation, timing of hearings and other matters relating to the case against Ross Ulbricht.

What website, or resource would have up-to-date information of upcoming arraignments and other matters pertaining to the case?

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer, let me point you to the three places of which I happen to know that they had more than one detailed report on the subject, starting the count with the arrest of Ulbricht. **Please note that this list is probably a better reflection of my personal browsing habits than than any objective standard about being particularly fast or complete sources.** All of these are deep links to local search results for "silk road":

1. [Popehat](http://www.popehat.com/?s=silk%20road)
2. [Tech Dirt](http://www.techdirt.com/search-g.php?q=silk%20road)
3. [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/search/?query=silk%20road)

Even better might be a news aggregator, such as [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/index2.pl?fhfilter=silk%20road) (again a deep link to search results for "silk road"). You won't find too much original content beyond a summary and one or more links, but it is fairly likely that major developments reported anywhere will find their way onto Slashdot.

Comment: Deep link to [Tech Dirt](http://www.techdirt.com/search-g.php?q=silk+road);
    deep link to [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/search/?query=silk+road)

Comment: I took the liberty of inserting the links into the response body.

Comment: Although technically separate from the legal investigation, [this NY Times blog](http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/11/23/study-suggests-link-between-dread-pirate-roberts-and-satoshi-nakamoto/) is noteworthy, for reporting that the online identity "Dread Pirate Roberts" that Ross is essentially accused of having may be closely linked to (or possibly even identical to) Satoshi himself. It is also noteworthy, in my mind, for not giving supporting links. Their only source's authors are named, though. It appears to be [this academic paper](http://cryptome.org/2013/11/bitcoin-pirate-nakamoto.pdf).